# Are missing buttons in the file properties window the new normal?

Tags: unity, nautilus, file-properties

I recently noticed that the buttons on the file properties window for my files are missing. Right clicking on a file or folder, and choosing "Properties", brings up the following window:

[image: Missing file properties buttons]

As can be seen, there are not buttons at the bottom portion. I'm quite certain there were some before.

So my question is, are the missing buttons the new normal? Or is something wrong with my system and do I need to do a reinstall of my OS? I am currently using Ubuntu 16.04 LTS. The file browser version installed is "Files 3.14.3".

Comment: same goes with me(no button at bottom portion). I guess this is not a problem, but just a DE setting.

Comment: If its a setting, then it's a setting I never switched on. I'm wondering if this is due to recent update, or if all 16.04 installs have this behavior.  I remember that that this window should look like this with the buttons: https://i.stack.imgur.com/L8pjT.png

Comment: I'm agree with you on this. perhaps it's due to recent updates as any changes made on the dialog box will saved immediately.